# bufferedReader readline=null

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader

im trying to write a class where it would take a text file,reverse its contents and write it back. The way i want to do it is to write the lines in a `String[]` array,reverse the lines and then write the text back to the text file. Problem is, when I start writing to the String array, it writes off only nulls and i know the text file is not empty. Im using a copy of the `BufferedReader` to read the lines. I can't seem to understand where am i wrong. When I initialize the `String` array textFile like down in the code, i have no problems reversing, but when i use the

```
String[] textFile = new String[getNumberOfLines ()];
```

method, it doesnt work.

```
public void reverse() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(WORK_FOLDER_LOCATION + FILE_NAME));
    String[] textFile = new String[3];
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < textFile.length; i++) {
            textFile[i] = reader.readLine();
            textFile[i] = reverseLine(textFile[i]);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException("There was a problem while operating with the reader.");
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    writeReverseText(textFile);
}

private int getNumberOfLines(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader linesReader = reader;
    int counter = 0;
    try {
        while (linesReader.readLine() != null) {
            counter++;
        }
        linesReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException("There was a problem while counting the lines");
    }
    return counter;
}

private String reverseLine(String string) {
    StringBuilder reversedString = new StringBuilder(string).reverse();
    System.out.println(reversedString);
    return reversedString.toString();

}

private void writeReverseText(String[] textFile) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(WORK_FOLDER_LOCATION + FILE_NAME));
    for (int i = 0; i < textFile.length; i++) {
        writer.append(textFile[i]);
        writer.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

**EDIT** I managed to solve the issue but changing the `getNumberOfLines()` method:

```
private int getNumberOfLines() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader linesReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(WORK_FOLDER_LOCATION + FILE_NAME));
```

Hope this helps to the others, i would love to know why the previous code didn't work.

Comment: @Mohit You seem to have lost part of the question in your edit. Don't do that.

Comment: thank you for correction

Comment: @EJP That's strange .. you think that the answer should be part of the question? ([Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288443/answer-embedded-in-question))

Answer (score 1):

Your `getNumberOfLines()` method will read all the data from the `BufferedReader` - so unless you start reading the file again, there's nothing to read, and the very first call to `readLine()` will return `null`.

However, instead of doing this, you'd be better off just reading the file once, and populating a `List<String>`. For example:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(reverseLine(line));
}
```

Comment: ye using Lists would be way easier. Sadly I cant use it because this is a part of my java course and we still haven't covered Lists yet. Thanks for the good answer tho, ill definately use your approach later on more serious tasks!

Comment: @ГеоргиЦанков Nevertheless the underlying point is sound. Once you've counted the lines, there are no more lines in that `BufferedReader`. You have to open a new one, and a new `FileReader` as well to wrap in it. Or, better still, devise a way to process the entire file in one pass. Compilers can do it: you can.

Comment: @ГеоргиЦанков: In that case, if you really want to write back to the same file, you either need to create an array big enough to hold any file you'll need to read (not ideal) or open the file twice. If you were writing to a *different* file, you could write each reversed line as you read it, without storing the whole file anywhere.